# How to set up current time datetime-local value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to set up the current date and time as the default value of `followup_date` field in my form. I have added `followup_date` as `datetime-local`.

I tried to set up current time as a default value by using following JavaScript code.

Please see my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
  alert(dateTime); //its working
  $("#followup_date").val(dateTime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="followup_date" name="followup_date" required>
```

It doesn’t work.

Comment: It's not clear what's your problem, explain more. I got value, work for me

Comment: i have edited the question. please see now

Comment: It's clear! your format not accept by datetime-local

Comment: what is the acceptable format ?

Comment: Take care in spelling `JavaScript` to avoid search collision with Java. And please take more care overall in your typing. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia and less like a chat room or messaging app.

Comment: Sure. I will take care about that in future postings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add also 0 before month, hour & date if values are less than two digits. eg. 1 => 01

Your ID selector was wrong

```js
function adjust(v){
if(v>9){
return v.toString();
}else{
return '0'+v.toString();
}
}
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+adjust(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+adjust(today.getDate());
var time = adjust(today.getHours()) + ":" + adjust(today.getMinutes());
var dateTime = `${date}T${time}`;
//its working

$("#followup_next_followup_date").val(dateTime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local"  class="form-control" onchange="alert(this.value)" id="followup_next_followup_date" name="followup_next_followup_date" required>
```